# HTML hex to polish characters

Tags: c#, html, hex

I'm downloading HTML file with polish characters, and parsing it to string by:

```
public static string HexToString(string hex)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < hex.Length; i += 2)
    {
        string hexdec = hex.Substring(i, 2);
        int number = int.Parse(hexdec, NumberStyles.HexNumber);
        char charToAdd = (char)number;
        sb.Append(charToAdd);
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

so when I found %21 I'm sending 21 to `HexToString()` and in return there is !, this is ok, but char ą is represented as %C4%85 (Ä) and I whant to get ą char

Comment: There's something wrong here. 0xC4 isn't a valid character in UTF8, and in the Polish code page (852) it's `─`. The code for `ą` in code page 852 is 0xA5

Comment: You ar right, ą char is send as %C4%85, not only %C4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you are treating the hex codes as if they are UTF16 (which is the native format for `char`), but they are in fact UTF8.

This is easy to resolve using a UTF8 encoding.

First, let's write a handy `StringToByteArray()` method:

```
public static byte[] StringToByteArray(string hex)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(0, hex.Length)
        .Where(x => x%2 == 0)
        .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(x, 2), 16))
        .ToArray();
}
```

Now you can convert the hex string to text like so:

```
string hexStr = "C485"; // Or whatever your input hex string is.

var bytes = StringToByteArray(hexStr);
string text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);

// ...use text
```

Answer (score 1):

Matthew is right, but you can also use this:

```
        public static string ConvertHexToString(string HexValue)
        {
            var res = "";
            var replacedHex = HexValue.Replace("%", String.Empty);
            while (replacedHex.Length > 0)
            {
                res += System.Convert.ToChar(System.Convert.ToUInt32(replacedHex.Substring(0, 2), 16)).ToString();
                replacedHex = replacedHex.Substring(2, replacedHex.Length - 2);
            }
            return res;
        }
```